# How is `git pull --rebase` different than `git reset --soft origin/b`

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-reset

I am trying to understand `git pull --rebase`...in order to do so, how is that command different from:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --soft remotes/origin/foo
git add .
git commit -am "bar"
git merge remotes/origin/foo
```

is `git pull --rebase` the same as the above commands or different? Certainly is less verbose, obviously.

Comment: `git pull` is just a shorthand for `git fetch` + `git merge`. `git pull --rebase` is `git fetch` + `git rebase` instead.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are quite different.

Assuming you have `master` checked out with a clean tree, your proposed set of commands will have the effect of pointing `master` at a single commit whose parent is the fetched upstream but whose *content* has the effect of replacing the new upstream tree with a copy of your pre-fetch `master`, without merging any of the upstream changes.  (In particular, the final `git merge remotes/origin/foo` will always say "Already up-to-date." and never make any changes.)

That's because the command:

```
git reset --soft remotes/origin/foo
```

sets `master` to point to `remotes/origin/foo` without changing the current working directory (or index).  Then, the command:

```
git commit -am "bar"
```

checks in a single commit for the (unchanged) tree from your current master.  As far as Git is concerned, you just freshly fetched the upstream, and then methodically changed it to look exactly like your own `master` based on an earlier upstream, undoing any changes made since your previous pull, and then checked it in on top of the upstream.  Since this commit is now a descendent of upstream, it's already considered merged, and the:

```
git merge remotes/origin/foo
```

will have no effect.

In constrast, `git pull --rebase` is the equivalent of

```
git fetch origin
git rebase remotes/origin/foo  # or wherever you pull from
```

This has the effect of **replaying** the **sequence** of commits that have been made on `master` since you last pulled from upstream on top of the upstream branch and pointing `master` at the result.

So, it differs from the above commands in that it adds a **sequence** of commits to upstream instead of adding a single commit, and it **replays** the contents of the commits (which means it tries to replay the changes made in those commits) on top of upstream, instead of replacing upstream with the old contents of `master` and obliterating upstream changes.  In the end, `master` is *still* a descendent of `remotes/origin/foo`, so running:

```
git merge remotes/origin/foo
```

would still do nothing, but it doesn't have to do anything, because newly fetched upstream changes will have been incorporated into the new `master` branch.

Comment: Note: the above assumes (at least at the moment I type this) that the current branch is `master`. (The `git reset` command always affects the current branch.) (It's a bit more correct to note that `git commit` commits based on the index contents, too, but `git commit -a` has the effect of running `git add --all` first, so that the index contents are updated according to the work-tree.)

Comment: Good point on being on `master`.  I edited the answer to mention this.  In this case, because the reset was soft, the index and working tree are actually the same, so the `git add` and `-a` flag for `git commit` don't do anything, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Right, that's why I said "a bit more correct" and put it in parentheses (though we're making the assumption that they started out the same!). If one were to use a mixed reset, the add step would change the index.